# UINavigationItem title in subsequent views doesn't update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Need help on this matter. I've recently installed update and is now running on XCode 9.4.1 and Swift 4.1. This was a previous project in Swift 3 and it got updated when I load it up after updating XCode.

This is how it looks like in XCode:
[image]

And this is how it looks like when running:

*Notice that the title always display "Dashboard" no matter what I change it to in the second view. It's always based on the first screen's title. Back button and any menu items added will not show up either. It happens to all other views as well no matter which button i tap on. The new screen slides in and the same title shows up again.

There's no codes modifying anything related to the titles / navigation bar.

[image]
[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: clean the project and try once again . else restart the xcode

Comment: Tried both, still didnt work. Even tried restarting my mac.

Comment: did you had a chance to test in real device . try resetting. the simulator or delete the app from simulator